# Deserialize json to c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How should my C# sharp object look like, I would like to deserialize the following JSON string to a C# object.

```
{   
   "PersonId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "Name": "XXXXXXXX",  
   "HobbiesCollection":
        {"Hobby":
            [
                {
                    "type": "RUNNING",
                    "id": 44,
                    "description": "sprinting and sprinting?"
                },
                {
                    "type": "RUNNING",
                    "id": 45,
                    "description": "jogging and jogging"
                }
            ]
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what is generated in VS2013

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Hobbiescollection HobbiesCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Hobbiescollection
{
    public Hobby[] Hobby { get; set; }
}

public class Hobby
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

You can use VS2012/2013 feature `Edit/Paste Special/Paste JSON As Classes` to simplify this process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a online tool you can make C# class from your String

[JSON to Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#)

```
public class Hobby
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class HobbiesCollection
{
    public List<Hobby> Hobby { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HobbiesCollection HobbiesCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I *just* posted an answer about json2csharp and saw that you were 53 secs faster. Heh. It's a great tool!